# Custom component container not stretching to allow content to grow

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular14

I'm faced with this issue that I never noticed before.

I have a custom component (`<field-info></field-info>`) whose HTML looks like

```
<span [ngStyle]="{ 'width' : cssWidth }" class="my-auto">
  <span>
    <span [innerHtml]="iconType" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="my-auto material-icons-outlined">
    </span>&nbsp;{{unitDisplay}}
  </span>
</span>
```

`cssWidth` is set to `75px` in this case. The problem is that the content above gets compressed on a single column because the `field-info` HTML element is not 75 pixel wide.

[image]

If I open Chrome dev tools and manually add `style: 75px;` to the `field-info` HTML element, then the component's content stretches correctly.

How do I tell my component to stretch to whatever width is needed to fit its own content exactly ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify the component's DOM this way:

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {

}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const ne = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    ne.style.setProperty("width", this.cssWidth);
    ne.classList.add("my-auto");
}
```

Now the component's width is set properly (cssWidth is an input variable) and I can also add a boostrap class to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use fit-content width option in your CSS!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content

Alternatively, auto lets the browser calculate the width for your element as well.